# Azure Data Factory architecture with Azure SQL database to Power BI

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm no MS expert - recently hopped onto the Azure train and apologies in advance if I get some information wrong.

Basically need some input in **Azure's architecture** utilising **Azure Data Factory** (as the ETL/ELT tool) and **Azure SQL database** (as the storage), to a BI output - Power BI. My situation is this;

- I have on-premise data sources such as *Oracle DB, Oracle Cloud SSAS, MS SQL server db*
- I'd like to have a MS cloud infrastructure solution for reporting purposes.
- No data migration needed - merely pumping on-prem data onto cloud and producing a BI reporting solution

Based on my limited knowledge and Google research, Azure Data Factory caters for all my on-prem sources, as well as the future cloud Azure SQL database. If future analysis is needed, **Azure Storage** and **Azure Databricks** can be added in to this architecture. I have sketched out the architecture of my proposed solution.
[image: Proposed Azure Architecture]

Just confirming my understanding

1. **Without** Azure Storage & Databricks (the 2 pink boxes), the 2 Azure component (DF & SQL database) is sufficient to take data from on-premise sources, process on cloud & output into Power BI.
2. **With** Azure Storage & Databricks (the 2 pink boxes), processing will be more efficient as their summarised function is to store training data models & act as an analytics processing engine.
3. **Azure SQL database** is more suitable, as compared to **Azure SQL datawarehouse** as my data sources does not exceed 1TB; cost-wise is cheaper AND one of my data sources contain data from call centers, hence OLTP is more suitable. Plus I have Azure Databricks to support the analytical bit that SQL datawarehouse does (OLAP).

Any other comments to help me understand this whole architecture will be great!

Answer (score 0):

I am a new learner of Azure. I was wondering if we have @Query (value="...") kind or any equivalence for DocumentDb (CosmosDB). Because, the documentDB does not take @Query. I am looking to convert the sql query (From jpa to cosmosDB).

Answer (score 0):

Taking data from on-prem or IaaS sources like SQL on a VM, Oracle etc, requires a [Self-Hosted Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime) (SHIR).

Please review the [Modern Data Warehouse](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/solutions/architecture/modern-data-warehouse/) pattern which sounds similar to what you are proposing.

Comment: But Data Factory supports SHIR so my initial architecture flow still stands. 
Thanks for the link to modern data warehouse. But in that diagram there is the existence of data lake; but the flow description calls it Azure Blob Storage. I thought they were a different component, with similar functionalities. Does that mean I need a Data Lake instead of Azure Storage? (as per my architecture diagram)

Comment: Azure Data Factory supports three types of runtime: the auto one, which does not require any additional VMs / infra plus the SSIS runtime and self-hosted integration runtime (SHIR) which do.  As you are moving data from on-prem datasources you need SHIR which in turn requires a VM / additional infrastructure and configuration so I think it’s worth calling it out.